# Kotlin - MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity, onRequestPermissionsResult function not found and cannot be overriden

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a trial activity class Main Activity that extends AppCompatActivity. In the docs, AppCompatActivity inherits the method onRequestPermissionsResult, when I try to override the said method onRequestPermissionsResult,
   this error shows up

> "Error:(95, 5) 'onRequestPermissionsResult' overrides nothing"

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(),  ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener{
    //I didnt include the other functions in the interfaces, suffice to say i have already added them in the original

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode : Int , permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: Array<Int>){
        println("SHOULD HAVE THIS FUNCTION")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kotlin `Array<Int>` is mapped to Java `Integer[]`, `IntArray` is mapped to Java `int[]`, they are different array types in Java. and you can see the [mapped types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#mapped-types) in Kotlin as further.

The [AppCompatActivity#onRequestPermissionsResult](http://android.xsoftlab.net/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#onRequestPermissionsResult(int,%20java.lang.String[],%20int[])) method signature is:

```
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode : Int , 
                                        permissions: Array<String>,     
                                        grantResults: IntArray){
    //      it is IntArray rather than Array<Int>   ---^  
    TODO()
}
```

Rather than:

```
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode : Int , 
                                        permissions: Array<String>, 
                                        grantResults: Array<Int>){
    TODO()
}
```

*Note*: if the api has promised that its parameters never be `null`, such as [onRequestPermissionsResult](http://android.xsoftlab.net/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#onRequestPermissionsResult(int,%20java.lang.String[],%20int[])) then you can use an `IntArray` to make the parameter easy to use. Otherwise, you should use `IntArray?` instead.

**IF** you don't want to know all of the [mapped types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#mapped-types) in Kotlin, there is another way that will make you override the super class methods quickly. First, put the cursor in the class, then press `CTRL+O` to select the methods to override. for example:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), 
                     ConnectionCallbacks,
                     OnConnectionFailedListener{
// put the cursor here, press `CTRL+O` to select which method you want to override
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your support and sharing your in depth knowledge